# How to make a layout with fixed sides and expandable center?

Tags: android

What do you think would be the best way to make such layout in android?

It should fill the screen's resolution, while having the left and right part fixed 150px in width, but the center part should stretch out as needed.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use RelativeLayout, and take Three Views init:

LayoutParams of EachView should be as:

View1--   id- @+id/view1
          Layout_Width= wrap_content
          Layout_Height=wrap_content

view2:    id- @+id/view2
          Layout_Width= fill_parent
          Layout_Height=wrap_content
          toLeftOF=@+id/view3
          toRightOf=@+id/view1

view3:   id- @+id/view2
          Layout_Width= wrap_content
          Layout_Height=wrap_content
          align_parent_right=true

Answer (score 3):

Best approach will be to use LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View 
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <View 
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View 
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html - this is probably what you are looking for, specifically http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns